# 'Unsupported driver' error when writing Geodataframe to file in geopandas

Tags: python, file, anaconda, geopandas

I am reading in a GeoJson file, applying some functions to it and then want to save the GeoDataFrame to another file.

Here's my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df=gpd.read_file('C:/in_folder/data.json')
df.to_file(driver='C:/out_folder', filename='df.json')
```

But this yields the following error:

> **DriverError**: unsupported driver: 'C:/out_folder'

Here's the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-4209247a0f42> in <module>
      1 import geopandas as gpd
      2 df=gpd.read_file('C:/in_folder/data.json')
      3 df.to_file(driver='C:/out_folder', filename='df.json')

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
    513         from geopandas.io.file import to_file
    514 
--> 515         to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
    516 
    517     def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False):

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
    125         schema = infer_schema(df)
    126     with fiona_env():
--> 127         with fiona.open(
    128             filename, "w", driver=driver, crs=df.crs, schema=schema, **kwargs
    129         ) as colxn:

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    396     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    397         if local._env:
--> 398             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    399         else:
    400             if isinstance(args[0], str):

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
    260             else:
    261                 this_schema = None
--> 262             c = Collection(path, mode, crs=crs, driver=driver, schema=this_schema,
    263                            encoding=encoding, layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, crs_wkt=crs_wkt,
    264                            **kwargs)

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in __init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
    126                 raise DriverError("no driver")
    127             elif driver not in supported_drivers:
--> 128                 raise DriverError(
    129                     "unsupported driver: %r" % driver)
    130             elif self.mode not in supported_drivers[driver]:

DriverError: unsupported driver: 'C:/out_folder'
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `driver` keyword needs to be a file format, like "ESRI Shapefile", or "GeoJSON", etc.

To see all supported drivers, you can run (the exact output depends on your installation):

```
>>> import fiona
>>> fiona.supported_drivers
{'AeronavFAA': 'r',
 'ARCGEN': 'r',
 'BNA': 'raw',
 'DXF': 'raw',
 'CSV': 'raw',
 'OpenFileGDB': 'r',
 'ESRIJSON': 'r',
 'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw',
 'GeoJSON': 'rw',
 'GeoJSONSeq': 'rw',
 'GPKG': 'rw',
 'GML': 'raw',
 'GPX': 'raw',
 'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw',
 'Idrisi': 'r',
 'MapInfo File': 'raw',
 'DGN': 'raw',
 'PCIDSK': 'r',
 'S57': 'r',
 'SEGY': 'r',
 'SUA': 'r',
 'TopoJSON': 'r'}
```

Answer (score 5):

The KML driver isn't enabled by default as detailed in this GitHub issue https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/97. Basically, the KML driver doesn't seem to meet Fiona's quality requirements (as of 2014), not sure if it will be fixed in the future.

You could try to enable KML driver which is disable by default.

```
import geopandas as gpd, fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
```

With newer versions of fiona, you might need to use libkml instead of kml. I.e.:

```
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['libkml'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled 
gpd.read_file("/path/to/your/test.kml")
```

Credits go to [this answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258370/186627)